# Cakephp 2.0 ACL implementation issue

Tags: cakephp, acl

I have created acos, aros and aros_acos tables. Values inserted in the "acos" table by using CakePlugin::load('AclExtras'). Also, values added in "aros" table automatically while adding Group ( In my case this is UserRole).

Also, when I added user in any Group ( UserRole in my case). Values are getting inserted in "aros" table as well as "user" table as expected.

Also, I have set permission in "aros_acos" table.

But, when I tried to login using any of added user I am getting following error:-

AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array ( [Aro0.model] => User [Aro0.foreign_key] => ) "

Following query printed:-

```
"SELECT `Aro`.`id`, `Aro`.`parent_id`, `Aro`.`model`, `Aro`.`foreign_key`, `Aro`.`alias` FROM `lms_new`.`aros` AS `Aro` LEFT JOIN `lms_new`.`aros` AS `Aro0` ON (`Aro`.`lft` <= `Aro0`.`lft` AND `Aro`.`rght` >= `Aro0`.`rght`) WHERE `Aro0`.`model` = 'User' AND `Aro0`.`foreign_key` IS NULL ORDER BY `Aro`.`lft` DESC"
```

facing road block here as I am unable to debug this issue. Please suggest how to proceed.

I have 4 types of User Role in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must put this code in User model:

```
public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester', 'enabled' => false));
```